# How can we add new list so that they are in the same row but different column with the dict in table html?

Tags: python, html, list

Here is my codes for the old list :

```
from collections import defaultdict

hello = ["hello","hi","hello","hello"]

def test2(strList):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for k in strList:
        d[k] += 1
    print('<table>')
    for i in d.items():
        print('<tr><td>{0[0]}</td><td>{0[1]}</td></tr>'.format(i))
    print('</table>')
```

And here is my new list:

```
hello2= ['bonjour','kiss']
```

Expected output:

```
<table>
<tr><td>hi</td><td>1</td><td>bonjour</td></tr>
<tr><td>hello</td><td>3</td><td>kiss</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what are you trying to achieve, because I doubt that this is the right way to do it...

Comment: I'm confused.  When did a dictionary creep in to your list?

Comment: Is hello.extend(hello2) what you want? This extends the hello list with items in list hello2.

Comment: @root edited... My expected output ;)

Comment: What is the logic behind that output?

Comment: @ErikaSawajiri -- I actually meant more broadly...Whats the purpose of this html you are trying to generate?

Comment: @root I have a homework that have one dictionary and one list.. And it says I must put them in one table with the same row but just different column.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would key the keys and the values in a dict and then have a separate inputlist from which you count the keys.

something like:

```
keys = {"hello":{"postfix":"bonjour", "count":0}, 
        "hi":{"postfix":"kiss", "count":0}}

frequencies = ["hello","hi","hello","hello"]

for item in frequencies:
    keys[item]["count"] += 1

print('<table>')
for k,v in keys.items():
    print("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>"
          .format(k, v["count"], v["postfix"]))
print('</table>')
```

And now I did your homework...